# Only positive and negative numbers in Javascript regex with zero or one minus symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^-0-9.]/g, '')
```

I use this code in my project, but input also can get more than 1 minus signs like this:

```
---23
```

I want my input to have these conditions:

1. only can get positive and negative numbers
2. zero or one minus

Comment: Regex isn't the right tool to tell if a number is in a certain range

Comment: Try `.replace(/^(-)+|[^\d.]/g, '$1')`

Comment: thank youuu Wiktor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.replace(/^(-)+|[^\d.]/g, '$1')

this is the right answer.

Comment: this doesn't capture any negative or positive integers..

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust your regex to below

EDIT.

Based on your requirements:

- positive or negative integers

```json
/^(-)?[0-9]*/g
```